# Memory usage in WPF application - how to track and manage? (BEGINNER SCOPE)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, memory, dataset

I have a small-scale WPF application using VB.net as the code behind and I want to add certain features, but i'm concerned about performance. I REALLY appreciate any responses especially if you could include beginner-friendly articles regarding this, but please help me so I can be at ease...

1) My app interacts with a third party database to display "realtime" data to the user. My proposed method is to create a background worker to query a database every 30 seconds and display the data. I query about 2,000 records all long integer type, store them in a dataset, and then use LINQ to create subsets of observable collections which the WPF controls are bound to.

Is this too intensive? how much memory am i using for 2,000 records of long int? Is the background worker querying every 30 seconds too taxing? will it crash eventually? Will it interfere with the users other daily work (excel, email, etc)?

2) If an application is constantly reading/writing from text files can that somehow be a detriment to the user if they are doing day to day work? I want the app to read/write text files, but I don't want it to somehow interfere with something else the person is doing since this app will be more of a "run in the background check it when I need to" app.

3) Is there a way to quantify how taxing a certain block of code, variable storage, or data storage will be to the end user? What is acceptable?

4) I have several list(of t) that I use as "global" lists where I can hit them from any window in my application to display data. Is there a way to quantify how much memory these lists take up? The lists range from lists of integers to lists of variables with dozens of properties. Can I somehow quantify how taxing this is on the app or the end user?

Thank you for any help and I will continue to search for articles to answer my questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you really want/need to get into the details of memory usage of an application you should use a memory profiler:

- http://memprofiler.com/ (commercial)
- http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/ (commercial)
- http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ (commercial)
- http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273 (free)
- http://www.scitech.se/blog/ (commercial)

Your other questions are hard to answer since all relevant aspects are rather unknown:

- what DB is used ?
- how powerful is the machine running the DB server ?
- how many users ?

etc.

On some things a performance profiler can help - for example the above mentioned memory profilers (esp. from RedGate / JetBrains etc.) usually are available in a packaged together with a performance profiler...

Comment: Thank you for the links! I will check them out. Honestly, it isn't super important, but I spend hours and hours trying to "optimize" as a beginner and it is just taking too long.. so I need to know if my efforts are for nothing. As for the questions about the database unfortunately I am not sure. It is an informix database, with several hundred users and I have no information about the machine. The query itself takes about 5-10 seconds to run and I would be running it every 30 seconds with a background worker.

Comment: @kdonah3 optimize only things that are a bottleneck... regarding the query - I think 5-10 seconds per run is alot, perhaps there is some index missing ? with so many users doing this query every 30 seconds it will a real problem IMHO. Is the result of the query user-specific ? or does it return for all users the same data ?

Comment: it returns the same data for all users, but only 5-6 users would be running this at one time. 5-10 seconds may be a bit long, yeah... I could likely get it down by retrieving fewer records.

Comment: @kdonah3 2000 records is not that much... to me it seems that the DB  and/or the network is rather slow... another point: please upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This helps other users looking for answers too...

Answer (score 2):

I will just try a few.  A byte integer uses a byte of memory.  An int32 uses 4 bytes.  So 2000 Int32 would use 8 kb.  If you have a query you need to run a lot and it takes 5-10 seconds you need to look close at that query and add any missing indexes.  If this is dynamic data then with (nolock) may be OK and faster with less (no) locking.  If the query is returning the same data for all users then I hope you don't have all users running the same query.  You should have a two tier application where the server runs the query every x seconds and sends that answer to the multiple clients that request it.   As for size of an object just add it up - a byte is a byte.  You can put you app in debug and get a feel for which statements are fast and slow.